# How to update a fixture file in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a fixture file in cypress which has json data within it

I want to be able to update the fields in this fixture file when I run the test script

For example the fixture file would read

```
 {
  table: [
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      number: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'Bob',
      number: 2,
    },
  ],
};
```

And I want to update the number fields to 3 and 4

I have tried

```
cy.fixture('dataFile.json')
  .as('data')
  .then((data) => {
    data.table[0].number = 3;
    data.table[1].number = 4;
  });
```

but it is not working
when I run the test i am still seeing everything behave as if the number fields are still 1 and 2.
If I print the fields to the console i can see they are actually updated but cypress is still running with the original data

I am still new to both cypress and javascript.
How can I get around this?

Answer (score 10):

The fixture can be read at the top of the spec file and modified for all tests in the spec.

This way you avoid unexpected problems when using the fixture in another spec

```js
const data = require('cypress/fixtures/dataFile.json')

data.table[0].number = 3
data.table[1].number = 4

it('tests with altered fixture', () => {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Modify fixture data *before* using it.

```
cy.fixture('user').then((user) => {
  user.firstName = 'Jane'
  cy.intercept('GET', '/users/1', user).as('getUser')
})

cy.visit('/users')
cy.wait('@getUser').then(({ request }) => {
  expect(request.body.firstName).to.eq('Jane')
})
```

From: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Modifying-fixture-data-before-using-it

Answer (score 5):

You have to use both [cy.readFile()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html) and [cy.writeFile()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#Syntax) to achieve this. You can write something like:

```
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/dataFile.json", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    };
}).then((data) => {
    data.table[0].number = 3
    data.table[1].number = 4
    cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/dataFile.json", JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

Comment: This worked for me. In addition you can do `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` to format the json file